# Some problems with INSERT INTO statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this mysql syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `utilizatori`(
  utilizator
)
SELECT
  'Mama'
FROM
  `utilizatori`
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  `utilizator` FROM `utilizatori` WHERE utilizator='Mama')
```

`utilizatori` is a table, `utilizator` is a column, `Mama` is a value

This syntax will insert a value in table only if it doesnt exist.If the value exist it wont create it,so until now it works fine,but if there is no 'Mama' value,then it will insert it...the only problem is that it will insert it multiple times.For example if i have 4 rows,it will insert 'Mama' value 4 times,creating 4 rows.Any idea??

Comment: this is an input? `SELECT 'Mama'` sidenote: if its an identifier, it should be using backticks

Comment: yes it's an input,when a user create an account i want to check if the username exists

Comment: you could simply have `utilizator` field to be `unique` so you don't need to check every time if it's already existent, and if it fail to insert, that means it already exists

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili , yes i could,but i also need an error message to show up if the username already exist.Thats why i tried like this

Comment: You check it by affected rows, if 0 affected means it already exists

Comment: so i should do an if with num_rows () = 0 echo "already exist" ??

Comment: Yes, you should. @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Put it as answer, I'll happily upvote.

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili , i will upvote and accept also,so post it as answer please

Comment: @Memphistoles OK thanks, I'll do it :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the task easier, clearer by making `utilizator` field `unique`.

That way when you add new rows with existing value `'Mama'` for `utilizator` in this case: mysql returns error with the code: `1062`, and don't let user have multiple rows with `Mama` in the table.

So when you run query:

```
INSERT INTO `utilizatori` (utilizator) VALUES ('Mama')
```

You can check if `MySQL` returns any error, but better to check number of affected rows, if insert was successful it will be equal to `1` otherwise `0`.

Checking mechanism depends what language and driver you use for connecting to database.

Since you had `PHP` tag selected you may be using `PDO` than

```
$statement->rowCount(); // $statement = PDOStatement, I assume you know this thing well
```

will give you desired result

**Final simple example:**

```
...
if ($statement->rowCount())
{
    echo "Cool! You have been added to database";
}
else 
{
    echo "Hmms! Are you trying to duplicate something?";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use group by :

```
INSERT INTO `utilizatori`(
  utilizator
)
SELECT
  'Mama'
FROM
  `utilizatori`
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  `utilizator` FROM `utilizatori` WHERE utilizator='Mama')
group by utilizator
```

Comment: You could also use `SELECT DISTINCT` syntax instead of `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

You are basically doing:

```
SELECT ... WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

...and inserting this in your table. As stated in the comments, just make your `utilizator` field unique and drop the whole `SELECT` part from your query.

Comment: and how can i put a condition if the value exist to show up an error with "Value already exist" ??

Comment: That's a different story. In that case, you would have a few bits of script (perhaps PHP and JavaScript) working together, first querying the database to see if it exists, returning the result and presenting it to the user. On a database level, the `UNIQUE` constraint will prevent from having duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Where Column is missing...

```
INSERT INTO `utilizatori`(
    utilizator
)
SELECT
  'Mama'
FROM
  `utilizatori`
WHERE
  'Mama'
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT  `utilizator` FROM `utilizatori` WHERE utilizator='Mama')
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT `utilizator` FROM `utilizatori` WHERE utilizator='Mama')' at line 1